# Macbook Pro says it’s charging but isn’t, both when plugged in and not plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging

I plugged my macbook in when it was on 10% and noticed it said not charging, so I unplugged to try a different cable but noticed when it was unplugged it still had the battery with the charging icon, and said it was plugged in (which it wasn’t) but not charging.

I restarted it but there was no change: the battery thought it was plugged in when it wasn’t and when it WAS plugged in it didn’t charge.

It’s since died and I can’t charge it to start it up again.

Comment: Sounds like your laptop has serious hardware problems nobody can diagnose over the web. I suggest you take it to a competent computer repair shop for physical diagnosis and repair.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC? This may fix the charging issues

Comment: If you can't turn on your Mac, there's nothing you'll be able to do.  It needs to go in for service.